# storing word by word and finding in java

Tags: java, find, storing-data

l am kind of trying to build a dictionary essay (storing words and then finding one of them after)

For example:
Sorting algorithm
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
A sorting algorithm is an algorithm that puts elements of a list in a certain order. The most-used orders are numerical order and lexicographical order. Efficient sorting is important for optimizing the use of other algorithms (such as search and merge algorithms) which require input data to be in sorted lists; it is also often useful for canonicalizing data and for producing human-readable output. More formally, the output must satisfy two conditions:
The output is in nondecreasing order (each element is no smaller than the previous element according to the desired total order);
The output is a permutation (reordering) of the input.
Further, the data is often taken to be in an array, which allows random access, rather than a list, which only allows sequential access, though often algorithms can be applied with suitable modification to either type of data.

l want to store this (above) in an array  or anything without reading the same word twice and find a word from it after.
What l tried so far is using an array[10000] to store things (in case not big enough) and scanner to read from a .txt file but things its taking a long time (5min+) without even starting to find
Also, if it is a book(100,000+ words), what should l be using to not wait so long(under 10min)?

l run a menu, then ask for a .txt to be read:

```
int number = 0;
String[] wordlist = new String[5000000];
String readFile = keyboard.nextLine();
Scanner file = null;
        file= new Scanner(new File(readFile));
        while (file.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            Scanner file = new Scanner(file.nextLine());
            boolean b;
            while (b = file.hasNext()) 
            {
                wordlist[number]= file.next();
                System.out.println(s);
                number++;
            }
        }
```

Then l do the checking after
and finding

Comment: Post your code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that

Comment: you are looking for better way that gives u less time?

Comment: less time and better code